# Scroll a ListView vertically on selection of item through keyboard when Scrollable = false

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I wanted to have only vertical scroll bar in ListView and so have that implemented using [ShowScrollBar Win32 API Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787601%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and made `listview1.Scrollable = false`

But with that the issue I am facing is: if I select an item in listview and keep going down using keyboard down arrow key; the vertical scroll doesn't scroll at all (It scroll only on mouse click).

Is there any way I can solve this problem. Please let me know.

Comment: @GrantWinney, yes absolutely but this Winform app is migrated from a legacy VB app where horizontal scroll is not present (you can just set the `flatscrollbar  = false`) and user wants it exactly that way. If there is no way then I will have to resort to enabling scroll in listview.

Answer (score 0):

As a first try and a dirty way on `KeyDown` event:

```
listView1.LabelEdit = true;
listView1.FocusedItem.BeginEdit();
SendKeys.Send("{Enter}");
```